# How to loop through the return values of a cmd in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a exec process task, in which i am just pinging 127.0.0.1 for testing.  Is there a way to retrieve the full response from the the execute process task and then loop through that response in SSIS 2005?

EDIT:

This is for an internal app.

I need to run the following from the cmd Line:

```
 dcAdmin /c jCount
```

which will produce something like this:

```
UserA:Active|d
UserB:Inactive|e
```

i need in an ssis package to loopthrough those UserX results

Comment: Needs more information. How does pinging a server have anything to do with examining a result set from a database?

Comment: FYI it's almost never good to `Loop through` result sets in SQL.  Use sets when possible!

Comment: folks are so judgmental. Perhaps you could just try to answer the question. it's not the goal of this service to ask why you want to do that, just to answer the question. He wants to take the out from an executable and then loop through it and do stuff in SSIS. if he could just do it all in a set in SQL, there would not be a post here, i presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing the output of the executable is easy enough using an Execute Process task:

[image]

This will put the entire standard output of the `dcAdmin` process in the `User::ProcessObject` variable. Without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish with this, I can't really make any suggestions about how to go further.